# Vps slow response

Tags: php, apache2, vps

I've bought a vps to transfer my back-end to it from a shared hosting. I've installed apache2, php, mysql server. My vps config:

- ram: 6 gb
- cpu: 6 cores
- ssd: 150 gb
- port: 1 Gbps
- os: Ubuntu 16.04

When I am making a test request, everything works on hight speed and I am receiving responses in 100 ms. But when my users (25-35k per day) start using this server, it becomes really slow. Sometimes I need a minute or two to get a response, sometimes the response does not come at all.

I am using my admin panel to check server load. It show me that all requests are just 400 KB of outgoing data per 5-10 minutes and less than 50 KB of incoming data. Server uses less, than a half of RAM available.

**My apache config is:**

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers       2
MinSpareServers    25
MaxSpareServers    75
ServerLimit        40
MaxClients         1000
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
        MaxRequestWorkers        500
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   100
</IfModule>
```

I really cant't understand, what thing can be a reason for such low response speed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your need to profile the app and see where the issue is, throwing more rockets at it wont speed it up. Whats the server load metrics? One of my sites has a constant stream of 150k+ hits a day (json/rpc), on a 1 core/1GB ram without issues.

Comment: My server load metrics: 1 min (Current: 0.03, Average: 0.01, Max: 0.03), 5 min: (Current: 0.01, Average 0.00, Max: 0.01). Ram usage: 250 mb. Traffic: 100 Kb. Yeah, I understand, that something is within my scripts, but the thing is that shared hosting with limited cpu/ram/bandwidth just works fine, the problem occurs only on vps

Comment: Post this on serverfault.stackexchange.com and hope for a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config file is confusing, which version of Apache are you running?

`MaxRequestsPerChild` became `MaxConnectionsPerChild` as of 2.3.9

`MaxClients` became `MaxRequestWorkers` as of 2.3.13

The old names are still supported, but you shouldn't have both.

Anyway, I guess the main problem is your `ServerLimit` and `MaxClients`/ `MaxRequestWorkers` values.

Let's assume each Apache instance is using 25MB of RAM (you can use `top` to get a rough idea of this, but as a ball park figure I'll run with 25MB). You have 6GB to play with but mysql needs some, so if you were to give Apache 3GB of it 3072/25 = 122.8 `MaxClients`

Your `MinSpareServers`/`MaxSpareServers` values are also high, I'd bring those right down.

I would start with something like this and tinker with the values for `MaxClients` / `ServerLimit` (use the same value for both) as well as `MaxRequestsPerChild`:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers 2
MinSpareServers 2
MaxSpareServers 5
MaxClients 100
ServerLimit 100
MaxRequestsPerChild 100
</IfModule>
```

Then restart Apache and stress test it.